# Why are my local notifications not having sound on by default in iOS 7?

Tags: iphone, ios, notifications, ios7, geofencing

My app uses geofencing and sends a notification.

By default, sounds are off in Settings - Notifications for the app.

iOS 7 to be precise.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Here is the code responsible for this:

```
UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
        localNotif.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:5 sinceDate:[NSDate date]];
        localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
        localNotif.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"You are near %@. Don't forget to check in!",place.name];
        localNotif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
        localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];
```

Comment: hi i got a geo fencing requirement am new to IOS ca you please share your sample code for to adding geo fencing in our application

Answer (score 2):

If the sound is turned off for your app in the Settings app, then your notification will not play any sound. The user does not allow you to do that.

If the sound is not turned off in the Settings app, that code that you posted should work.

Also if the user set the ringer switch off, then there will be no sound played.

Comment: Yes, but there is no seeming way to turn sounds on in the notification from the start... at least with local notifications...

Comment: I just ran the code that you've posted and it works :/ did you try testing it on the device instead of the simulator?

Comment: I have. No sound unless I explicitly turn it on in Settings - Notifications. Running on an iOS 7 iPhone 5S.

Comment: I ran into the same problem. Were you able to fix it?

Comment: @danielwinter That code works for me and I can hear the sound in the device. I'm not sure why he couldn't hear it.

Comment: i do hear it once i activate it (sound) throughout the notification settings. but this setting is off by default. could reproduce this both via a native app answell as a phonegap app with notification plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the applicationIconBadgeNumber in

`- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`?

Comment this code, and try again.....I don't why, but I got the same problem. After I commented this line, my app works correctly.